# PrimeReact DataTable background colour

Tags: reactjs, background-color, primeng-datatable, primereact

Am using PrimeReact DataTable in my React application.I have a requirement to change the background colour from white to grey in the DataTable..I tried custom style in the component. But not working..
Can you please help me?

Comment: do you want for the whole datatable to be in grey?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to override the style of the `Datatable` then use this css

```
.p-datatable-tbody tr {
  background: gray !important;
}
```

or, in order to avoid `!important`

```
.p-datatable .p-datatable-tbody > tr {
  background: gray
}
```

Comment: Its working ... I added  .p-datatable-header and .p-datatable .p-datatable-thead > tr > th